# "another ... than" is a correct usage?

Tags: phrases

There is a document basically written in English, but sometimes written in other languages exceptionally.

In that case, to identify the document not written in English,

> (a document) written in another language than English

is a correct expression?

This document is written in only one language, so

> (a document) written in other languages than English

seems wrong for me.  (Doesn't this imply the document is written in many languages?)

Of course "other ... than" is a common expression; how about "another ... than" is?

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one document mentioned that is not written in English, you could say "a document written in a language other than English." [singular/singular]

If there are multiple documents in various languages, you should say "documents written in languages other than English." [plural/plural].

However, there is a simpler and shorter way to say this that avoids the singular/plural problem nicely:

- Document(s) **not written in English**

It is obvious that if they are not written in English, they are written in some other language.  Then, you would only need to clarify *if there actually was some single document that is written in more than one non-English language*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

`Another` comes from `an + other`  [[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/another)]

You are saying:

> a language other than English

or

> an other language than English

and so, we have

> another language than English

voilà!

[See this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+boy+than%2Cboy+other+than%2C+other+boy+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canother%20boy%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboy%20other%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cother%20boy%20than%3B%2Cc0)

Note that the first sentence here is the most idiomatic way of putting it.

Comment: Who is Viola and how is she relevant to the question? ;-)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist: I should get a proofreader!

Comment: A51, I believe the reason the first construction is favored is because it separates the "a" (or, an) from "other," and thereby avoids being read as one word. This reveals that effort is being expended to avoid that particular reading. Ps: you've got a couple hundred thousand proof-readers, here.

Comment: I can't speak for what sounds "normal" in other parts of the world, but to my New York ear, "another language than English" sounds awful, even though it's as logical as a geometrical proof. But colloquial English is not always based on what's logical, so I'd have to go with Brian's answer instead (which is an answer other than this one.).